# ROS2 ros2_control/hardware_interface/ - working example?

Tags: ros, ros2, hardware-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Iam getting ready to migrate to ROS2, so I have to get my hw interface class working there. I had a look at [github ros2_controls](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/tree/master/hardware_interface) and it seems to be very different. Any direction or links to a more in detail explanation, tutorials or working examples would be highly appreciated. Also I couldnt find any kind of documentation, is there any?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374847/ros2--ros2_control/hardware_interface/---working-example?/) by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 574 on 2021-03-28

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have been strugling with the same issue and took me few days to figure it out.
I commited my WIP code so u can see an exampled.
https://github.com/DeborggraeveR/ros2-mecanum-bot

This is a simular approuch as my ROS1 robot which is using the RobotHW interface and communicates with arduiono:
https://github.com/DeborggraeveR/ampru

I don't have a tutorial yet, but here is a quick summary of what i done so far

**Visualize the robot**
Create the mecanumbot_description package with urdf model
Create the mecanumbot_bringup package with launch file for robot_state_publisher & join_state_publisher to be able to visualize the robot model in rviz2

**Add the hardware interface**
Create the mecanumbot_hardware package and implement a "hardware_interface::SystemInterface" class.
Most important line in this class is:

```
hardware_interface::CommandInterface(
            info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &velocity_commands_[i]
        )
```

If the joint name = wheel_joint, we map /joint_state/wheel_joint/velocity to "velocity_command_"
So if the velocity changes, the value will be stored in the "velocity_command_" which u can read during the "write" call.
Important on making this package work:

- Add the plugin xml on the root of the package
- Add the "PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS" in your hardware class
- Add the "pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file" in your CMakeList file

Next you need to define the joints used by the hardware in the URDF file (see bottom of my URDF => ros2_control node)
I also added the controller config file to the description package

**Use the hardware class**
Next i removed the "joint_state_publisher" from the bringup package launch files and added ros2_control
When u launch this, it wont work.
U can call "ros2 control list_hardware_interfaces" to see your hardware and notice all joint are unclaimed
U can call "ros2 control list_controllers" to see there are no active controllers

Next is to get your joint state published, this seems to do the same as the "joint_state_publisher" which is now commented out in my launch files

```
ros2 control load_start_controller joint_state_controller
```

Still the hardware is unclaimed.
I tried with running "ros2 control load_start_controller diffbot_base_controller" to launch the DiffDriveController.
I found example of this in PR or ros2_control_demos repo:
https://github.com/BorgesJVT/ros2_control_demos/tree/demo_diff_drive_controller

**Custom controller**
As i'm working on a mecanum bot, i also created a mecanumbot_controller package, which contains the controller.
Important part of the controller is that it subscribes to "/cmd_vel".
Run "ros2 run teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard" to publish those messages
The controller added the joints used by the hardware in the "command_interface_configuration" method. This causes running this controller to claim the joins (ros2 control list_hardware_interfaces)

During the update of the controller i set the velocity as value of the "hardware_interface::LoanedCommandInterface"
This causes the variable mapped in the hardware to be updated.

**Auto launch controllers**
I have a open question here on the board on how to spawn the controllers trough launch files.
As workaround i added the mecanumbot_control packages, where the main method is the same as the ros2_control controller_manager main and where i add, configure & start my controllers

**Final**
When i run the teleopt_twist_keyboard and "move" the robot around, the "hardware::write" method will log the velocity of the wheel has change :)

Kind regards,

---

Originally posted by [RandyD](https://answers.ros.org/users/29157/randyd/) with karma: 161 on 2021-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RandyD](https://answers.ros.org/users/29157/randyd/) on 2021-03-28**:
note: when u use the DiffDriveController, i might notice the model flickering in rviz and saying the tf messages are invalid. Not sure if this is a bug or if i did something wrong, but with my custom controller i dont have this issue

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2021-03-29**:
Thank you very, very much @RandyD!!

**Comment by [RandyD](https://answers.ros.org/users/29157/randyd/) on 2021-04-02**:
@Dragonslayer
Updated my repo, which is now capable to drive the robot using a xbox-one controller connected to the raspberry pi running ros2 with ros2_control & hardware interface

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2021-04-03**:
Thanks. Are you on pi4?

**Comment by [RandyD](https://answers.ros.org/users/29157/randyd/) on 2021-04-03**:
yes rpi4, works great :)

**Comment by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on 2022-11-17**:
Hello there,

I am using ros2-humble version

When I looked at the links above, I saw that it was no longer working and the message I got as an error;
Hardware_interface/base_interface.hpp: No such file or directory.

I would appreciate it if you could help me find a working example.

**Comment by [OverloadedSlime](https://answers.ros.org/users/124506/overloadedslime/) on 2022-11-20**:
@RandyD I'm not sure but in my case, the flickering stopped after setting enable_odom_tf to false.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here are a couple more examples:

https://github.com/frankaemika/franka_ros2/tree/develop/franka_hardware

https://github.com/husky/husky/tree/galactic-devel/husky_base

---

Originally posted by [tnajjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/36992/tnajjar/) with karma: 166 on 2022-05-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

https://control.ros.org/master/index.html

This is the official documentation for ROS2 Control!

Here is another good example:

https://github.com/joshnewans/diffdrive_arduino